# Update the img src in wordpress media library

Tags: jquery, wordpress, blogs, media-library

I wanted to update the img src rendered in wordpress media library

```
<a href="https://sample/group/wp-admin/post.php?post=159&amp;action=edit" title="Edit &#8220;NTPIII_Banner_41620134.jpg&#8221;">

<img src="http://sample/group/files/2014/01/NTPIII_Banner_41620134.jpg" class="attachment-80x60" alt="NTPIII_Banner_41620134.jpg" />                </a>
```

I wanted to replace HTTP to HTTPS as image is not showing when the src is HTTP

Comment: You have 2x `//` between `group` and `files` in your `<img>` src, which would prevent the image from showing.

Comment: Thanks, I just mistakenly pasted the extra slash while posting. I'll just update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var newSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('http', 'https');
    $(this).attr('src',newSrc);
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TWQ3m/

Comment: Thanks, I've just added this in the php file and it works like a charm!